# How to have upstart shutdown rsyslog as last job in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rsyslog, upstart

It seems like upstart decides to shutdown rsyslog on Ubuntu 14.04 as one of the first jobs if a machine shuts down. So most logging of shutting down jobs is lost. How to I instruct upstart to shutdown rsyslog as last job in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't use systemd. What's going on here?

Comment: you are right. changed question to upstart.